# Making Http call from one api to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I inject parameters in the Test method in my payment controller via postman.
Then I try to communicate these values via an Http post to a method in the bank controller.
But when I am testing in postman , the values returned from the bank controller are always returning null.

**Payment Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromQuery] Payment payment)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:6600/api/bank"; 
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                return Ok(movies);

            }
```

**Bank Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult PaymentDetails(Payment payment)
        {
             return new JsonResult(payment);
        }
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: What is localhost:6600? Is it running? What happens when you debug? Step through? What payload are you passing in your `GET` request? Are you (sending any payload in a `GET`)? Why is there a dance between 2 `controllers`?

Comment: is debugging a lost art? that's your first check

Comment: You need to update your url with query string that is created from initial Payment model, because right now you are not passing anything to bank controller.